# Arithmetic shift acts as a logical shift, regardless of the signed variable

Tags: verilog, bit-shift, system-verilog

I've got a register declared as so:

```
logic signed [15:0][2:0][15:0] registers;
```

When I place a 2's compliment number into the array and arithmetically shift the number, it logical shifts instead:

```
registers[0][0] = 16'b1000000000000000;
registers[0][0] = registers[0][0]>>>2;
```

Apparently, the system will logical shift instead of arithmetically shift if the number is not signed. However as you can clearly see, 'registers' is definitely signed.

Does anybody know what I might be missing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With Verilog, once you take a part-select, the result is `unsigned`. Use the `$signed` system task on the part select to make it signed.

```
res = $signed(registers[0][0]) >>> 2;
```

Comment: Is this synthesible? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: In SystemVerilog, you can also use a cast  `res = signed'(registers[0][0]) >>> 2;` Both should be synthesizable

Comment: for me, it just worked as follows: `res = $signed(registers[0][0] >>> 2);`