# Synthesizable arithmetic shift in Verilog

Tags: verilog, bit-shift

I recently came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14197331) on stackoverflow.

> With Verilog, once you take a part-select, the result is unsigned. Use the `$signed` system task on the part select to make it signed.

Is this method synthesizable (ie the system task `$signed`)

If it is not synthesizable, is there a different way to perform arithmetic shift on variables like `a <= a>>>2` (this should give the quotient when `a` is divided by 4).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly is synthesizable. Whether your particular tool supports it is another question.

You can also use a cast in SystemVerilog.

```
res = signed'(registers[0][0]) >>> 2;
```

Comment: I will be using Vivado. Target is a Xilinx Zedboard

Comment: Then it should support it