# Why does inlining a Verilog arithmetic shift turn it into a logical one?

Tags: verilog, bit-shift

I've read [multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197117/arithmetic-shift-acts-as-a-logical-shift-regardless-of-the-signed-variable) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52237539/synthesizable-arithmetic-shift-in-verilog) on how to implement an arithmetic shift in Verilog.  All suggest using `$signed(…) >>> …`.

This works when directly assigning the result to a wire or register, but not when using it as part of a larger expression.  That is:

- `reg[2:0] a =        $signed(3'b100) >>> 1         ;` produces `3'b110`
- `reg[2:0] a = 1'b1 ? $signed(3'b100) >>> 1 : 3'b000;` produces `3'b010`

The fix seems to be to wrap the computation into `$unsigned`:

- `reg[2:0] a =        $unsigned($signed(3'b100) >>> 1)         ;` produces `3'b110`
- `reg[2:0] a = 1'b1 ? $unsigned($signed(3'b100) >>> 1) : 3'b000;` produces `3'b110`

**Why does inlining the arithmetic shift cause it to act like a logical one, and why does adding `$unsigned` around it fix the issue?**

Here is a minimal working example:

```
module puzzle();
   reg [2:0] a_u = 3'b100 >>> 1; // 3'b010
   reg [2:0] a_s = $signed(3'b100) >>> 1; // 3'b110
   reg [2:0] a_mux = 1'b1 ? $signed(3'b100) >>> 1 : 3'b000; // 3'b010

   reg [2:0] b_u = $unsigned(3'b100 >>> 1); // 3'b010
   reg [2:0] b_s = $unsigned($signed(3'b100) >>> 1); // 3'b110
   reg [2:0] b_mux = 1'b1 ? $unsigned($signed(3'b100) >>> 1) : 3'b000; // 3'b110

   initial begin
      $display("a_u = 3'b%3b", a_u);
      $display("a_s = 3'b%3b", a_s);
      $display("a_mux = 3'b%3b", a_mux);

      $display("b_u = 3'b%3b", b_u);
      $display("b_s = 3'b%3b", b_s);
      $display("b_mux = 3'b%3b", b_mux);
   end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
a_u = 3'b010
a_s = 3'b110
a_mux = 3'b010
b_u = 3'b010
b_s = 3'b110
b_mux = 3'b110
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two Verilog expression rules at play here:

- Context-determined versus self-determined expressions
- In context, mixing signed and unsigned operand results in everything unsigned

When you have the expression

```
C ? A : B
```

The operands `A` and `B` are in context with each other. Each operand will be resized to largest operand, and both must be signed to remain signed. This happens *before* applying the operator during compilation. `S` is self-determined—nothing outside whatever `C` is has any effect on its size or signedness. Also, `C` has no effect on the context of `A` and `B`

Similarly when you have the expression

```
A >>> S
```

`A` is context-determined and `S` is self-determined

Now if we combine the two expressions into one:

```
C ? A >>> S : B
```

Since `A` and `B` are in the same context and `B` is unsigned, `A` gets converted to unsigned. As soon as you wrap `A>>>S` in a function call (any kind of function call works the same), each input argument to function has its own context independent of the rest of the expression it's part of. The return value will be treated in context with the rest of the expression.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Is there a cleaner way to give an expression it's own context, rather than using `$unsigned`?

Comment: I wouldn't call it *clean*, but it's fewer characters using a concatenation. `1'b1 ? {3'sb100) >>> 1} : 3'b000`. All operands in a concatenation are self-determined.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the reason but it seems that converting `3'b000` into `3'sb000` also solves your problem.

```
reg [2:0] a_mux = 1'b1 ? $signed(3'b100) >>> 1 : 3'sb000;
```

Also, using `$signed()` instead of `$unsigned()` works as well:

```
reg [2:0] b_mux = 1'b1 ? $signed($signed(3'b100) >>> 1) : 3'b000;
```